# Density of Truncated (partial) Sums of Basis

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $X$ be an uncountable subset of $L^1(\mathbb{R})$, whose span is dense in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$; ie:
$$
\overline{\operatorname{span}(X)}=L^1(\mathbb{R}).
$$

Fix and an integer $N>1$ and consider
$$
X_N\triangleq \left\{
\sum_{i=1}^N k_i x_i :\, k_i\in \mathbb{R},\, x_i \in X
\right\}.
$$

Does it follow that $X_N$ is dense in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true. Let $X=\{I_{(a,b)}: a <b\}$. Then span of $X$ is dense in $L^{1}$. In this case $X_2$ is obviously not dense.  For example $e^{-|x|}$ is not in the  closure of $X_2$.

Comment: Is there a reasonable "sufficient condition" on X or on $N$ for $X_N$ to be dense?

Comment: You just cannot expect denseness of $X_N$ for fixed $N$. The only way to get a dense set is to allow $N$ to vary.

Comment: @KaboMurphy  If $X$ is already itself dense, then $X_N$ is dense.

Comment: @AIM_BLB Of course, But I am sure OP is looking for a better result than that.

Comment: Yes, but the question I'm trying to ask OP is if: $X_N$ is dense if and only if $X$ is dense.